Why is the lower cost gained by cheap illegal immigrant labour used as an argument in America?
As a non-American, the whole illegal immigrant discourse is a bit questionable for me.
The Democrat adjacent side gives a lot of justification why illegal immigration needs to be tolerated and in certain smaller scales even legalized.
One of the arguments given is the "Who will pick the fruit's argument?", which says that without illegal immigrants, products and services will be more expensive.
Illegal immigrants are paid under the minimum wage usually, while from all I read they are paying taxes but indirectly by the deduction of pay through their SS which means they shouldn't be able to file an actual tax report without getting caught.
The reason they capable of working for such wage is due their illegal status and their lack of negotiation capabilities, as they can't use labour laws in their favor. Additionally, if they get citizenship, they legally are not allowed to work under minimum wage.
The argument doesn't make sense for me because it gives the argument to soften labor laws instead of illegals being useful for the society.

More info: Americans giving rather odd arguments why we shouldn't deport illegals - on Twitter / X, Youtube and Instagram (the only clip I could find CNN saying it)
Arguments given about how it lowers cost:

Five ways undocumented immigrants are powering the American economy

Mass Deportation: Devastating Costs to America, Its Budget and Economy

Mass Deportations Would Impoverish US Families and Create Immense Social Costs

Economic benefits of illegal immigration outweigh the costs, Baker Institute study shows



Your latest edit makes this seem like a push question as it appears to be using sources that are strongly supporting deportations.

@JoeW - Well, yes, it was obviously a push question from the outset. The use of the term "illegals" was evidence enough of that. Interesting how the solution of the minority of allegedly left anti-immigrant types is rarely "regularize them to mitigate wage depression," "increase taxation on wealthier people to allow supporting immigrant and native-born workers alike," or even "increase foreign aid spending to make countries of origin more attractive to stay in," but rather the right-wing standby of "send them back to the life that they crossed continents to leave, but with even less money."

First, I would like to point out that this argument has been criticized, not necessarily for being incorrect, but for ignoring what some people see as more fundamental concerns of human rights. That is, some people think that an instrumentalist approach to immigration is simply morally wrong; many supporters of "open borders" represent the most extreme example of this, asserting that the right to go wherever one pleases is a fundamental human right regardless of whether it produces benefits or drawbacks. Conversely, of course, some supporters of what they might describe as a "law and order" perspective are against undocumented immigration even if it does help a nation's economy. This is an occasional, although not usually dominant, view in many right-wing parties.
That said,  first, some people who support increased immigration do support relaxing labor laws. This is most prominent with the libertarian branches of the American conservative movement, as represented by organizations such as the Cato Institute, which historically has supported both increased immigration, including regularization of undocumented immigrants, and substantially reducing or eliminating child labor laws.
But second, and perhaps more important, the economic contribution of immigrants to the US economy (and to many other economies) does not depend on them being paid illegally low wages. As discussed here, the economic benefits of immigration come from factors such as an increased tax base, an increased supply of low-paid and high-paid labor, increased spending, and so forth, and otherwise from many, many factors other than "fruit picking." Even focusing on the aspect that is often most discussed, low-wage jobs, the idea is that there is a labor shortage even at legal minimum wages, but that some immigrants are still more likely to take a minimum-wage job that pays them much more than they would have made in their country of origin, or will have to take that job due to lack of English skills and so forth. This effect does not depend on immigrants skirting labor laws; although that factor certainly enhances it, there is nonetheless an effect of higher availability of low-skilled labor at legal wages.

Well in this case I am talking about Democrats and or progressive which I encounter often online using this argument.
Which in my eyes is not compatible with the other virtues and policies people like them promote, like workers rights, the increase of minimum wage, upwards mobility and equality.
People who complain about corporate greed coming in support of a exploitative practice is kinda ironic.
https://xcancel.com/nomorecolonies/status/1860111338661642629#m
https://x.com/piyushmittal/status/1858963425432662139

@Questioner - And here I thought you were asking a question and looking for an answer, which is what this site is for. Now, if you're actually looking for more details on why progressives sometimes use those arguments, I can provide them, but if you just want to make your own point that they "should" actually be anti-immigration, or tough on undocumented immigrants, that would be a waste of my time. Which one is it?

Well you gave me an answer to that though it kinda did go off the rails with conservative and libertarians.
"Now, if you're actually looking for more details on why progressives sometimes use those arguments, I can provide them"
I do want them because for me its seems to go against what progressive belief.

@Questioner - For most progressives, it's actually a human rights argument: the idea of sending people back to a life that was bad enough for them to uproot themselves to a completely different country is distasteful to them. That argument about making the economy better is something they use to convince conservatives. I did also point out that the economic benefits of immigration are not dependent on immigrants being paid illegally low wages, so progressives often push for policies that would protect undocumented immigrants from exploitative employers or outright regularize their status.

Also, progressives, especially the most radical ones, are often maximalist. They'd rather aim for redistribution of wealth via increased taxation of the wealthy (or relatively wealthy) and protecting immigrants who are often effectively refugees from poverty, war, or sexist and racist violence, rather than sending them back to face all that, at the same time, in much the same way that they don't see fighting for White people living in poverty and Black people living in poverty as goals that need to conflict (even though those groups also compete economically!)

@Questioner - One other thing to note is that you are getting some answers here from questioners who basically espouse left-wing anti-immigration policies. While they do represent a real line of thought on  the left, they are honestly out of step with its main trajectory today. E.g. looking at pan-European political parties, the Greens want expanded visas, a route to citizenship for foreign students, and regularization of undocumented immigrants, the Party of European Socialists supports the New Pact and wants better treatment of refugees.

And the European Left wants to "intervene in favor of refugees and immigrants in the public discourse," oppose "neoliberalism xenophobic policies," and avoid immigrants being used as "scapegoats" for the "'profit over people' dogma." Not that this is entirely universal: the Socialist International has become a bit more ambiguous since the 2004 meeting when it declared migration a "human right," but it's still basically in favor of "higher levels of legal, permanent migration."

So while it's good that they are sharing their opinions, I don't think they are entirely meeting your request of providing reasoning for why progressives often support the rights of undocumented and documented immigrants, either. Saying that "it's just the neoliberals and capitalists," when it's arguably among some of the most radical anti-capitalist socialists that you would find the most radical pro-immigration views today, is incomplete.

So far your answeres where the best I got for a long time.
At least you try to act like a rational human being opposed to those idiots on Quora.
Thank you very much.

Note that the equation becomes a lot more complex if the illegals bring in their family or end up staying long enough to get Medicaid, or returning on social security later in life. Having a child in school for example would make most illegals a net negative for the economy.

This argument is used primarily by neolibs and people who are not from the working class whose priorities are maintaining their status quo which they benefit from, themselves being in high-income positions/jobs e.g. entertainment or consulting or finance or politicians who take money from multinational companies' lobbyists i.e. corruption like Kamala Harris.
People like Bernie Sanders who advocate for a strong social safety net state are not in favor of immigration because it will divert resources that would otherwise go to the natives and reduce the original population's standard of living.
Immigrants depress wages and compete with local labor force. The illegals compete in construction and agro industry, undercutting incomes for the working-class because of higher supply of unskilled labor. This of course benefits the bourgeoisie and landowning class who exploit the illegals because they are willing to work for less, having come from poor countries.
Another issue is the H1B visa immigrants from India who compete with our college graduates for jobs and who are imported in droves by the neolibs because they are willing to work for less and for longer hours having come from countries with no labor rights and protections.
Despite what the mainstream media and influencers try to tell you, these immigrants decrease our social surplus and workers' standard of living since they undercut wages and often send back remittances to their home countries, taking the money out of our economy. They lie to you by saying that GDP increases, all while the actual standard of living of people decreases, because while the fat-cats at the top benefit immensely from immigrant labor, the domestic working class here in America is left worse off by increased competition from people who will accept lower living standards.
TLDR: the ruling/bourgeoisie classes benefit from immigration at the expense of the decrease in standard of living of the working class.

I agree with you but I need more sources on that

exploit the illegals because they are willing to work for less => would be a perfect answer if not for this. No one is being “exploited”, these people come to the U.S. because that’s better than staying at home. Information on what job conditions are truly like is now 100% ubiquitous and available in dozens of languages, with ~99% of incoming workers having some form of internet access these days. Technology has completely annihilated this type of arguments.


The argument doesn't make sense for me because it gives the argument to soften labor laws instead of illegals being useful for the society.

Yes. Illegal immigrant labour is used by businesses to depress labour wages, and even take advantage of them to bypass labour laws (like making them work longer hours, not giving them paid sick leaves etc.). Businesses want that. America is built on capitalism, where the concerns of the businesses are often given the highest priority.
It is not as if businesses that support Republicans are against this idea of cheaper labour and weaker labour laws too. However, what they want is more insidious when you consider the rights of American workers. Republican political counter to cheaper labour from illegal immigrants is to make American labour itself cheaper (by depressing and preventing raise of minimum wages) and to weaken labour laws for everyone in America. Some of the ideas for this include relaxing worker ages to allow even teenagers to return to factories, instead of going to school (if they want to), making it more difficult for students to gain a higher education so they are forced to work right after school, banning unions so that workers cannot politically organise to protect their rights etc.
The Democrats understand the need of cheaper labour, but they also do not want to rollback hard won labour rights that does distinguish American labour from those of underdeveloped or developing countries where labour exploitation are rampart because of weaker (or non-existing) labour laws.
Thus, their approach is that since America is a country of immigrants, America does not need to fear immigrants. Even illegal immigrants (unless they are criminal elements or a danger to national security as spies etc).
If they aren't a danger to American society, they feel it is ok to let the illegal immigrants work and contribute to the American economy so that they aren't a drain on society. And that they will be temporarily exploited (by lower wages, longer hours etc.) should be seen as an acceptable form of punitive measure for being an illegal in the US (akin to a fine for non-compliance). This kind of labour exploitation can also act as a deterrent for other immigrants planning to come illegally to the US. But if these illegals are law abiding decent human beings and hard workers contributing to the American economy, the Democrats also believe that some of these people should be given the legal opportunity to become American citizens eventually.
After all, they've been "punished" with lower wages and are still willing to make America their home, America is a country built by immigrants and it continues to depend on them for its economic and cultural growth.
Note that Democrats don't believe that immigrants entering America illegally is good. But they believe that this political issue should be handled with a more humane approach than treating them as criminals. Every developed country gets illegal immigrants. Democrats believe their partial solution of temporarily letting businesses exploit them for cheap labour is better than American tax payer paying for their arrest, detention and eventual deportation. With their way, the illegals who are in America won't be a drain on American economy because cheaper labour makes American businesses more competitive, while the undesirable criminal elements amongst the illegals will definitely be deported.

Republicans also claim "They're taking jobs away from Americans." The problem with this is that Americans demonstrably don't want these jobs.

There is some good stuff in this answer, but "And that they will be exploited should be seen as an acceptable form of punishment for being an illegal in the US" is very far from what most Democrats think. At best, they think undocumented immigrants should have the same labor protections as documented ones; at worst, they don't particularly care about them not having those protections, but one way or another, the notion of people deserving to be "punished" for being "an illegal" is way outside the mainstream of the Democratic Party.

It is within the mainstream of the Republican Party, but the Republicans who endorse that think the correct punishment is deportation or imprisonment, while "the chance to make money in the greatest nation on Earth while not paying any taxes and taking money from real Americans," as they would see it, is something they consider a reward, if anything.

@Obie2.0 I judge politicians by what they do, not what they say. And it is an undeniable fact that illegal immigrants don't have uniform labour protections in the US. The Democrats have been in power for the last few years and the situation is still the same. While I will concede that "punishment" may not be the right word with respect to exploitation of illegals, you also cannot ignore that America is a country that has adopted a strong sense of right and wrong in their justice system where it is felt that the smallest of infringement or deviation from law needs to be harshly punished.

I think you're conflating the fact that many Democrats don't particularly care about exploitation of undocumented immigrants with the idea that they consider it a punishment, when really, your other idea that they consider it good for business can already explain a good portion of that attitude. As I've said, the people who think immigrants should be punished exist, but they tend to vote Republican and consider deportation or imprisonment the appropriate punishment. People who see exploitation as a moral penalty for crossing the border must exist, but they are not common or usually Democrats.

" Even illegal immigrants (unless they are criminal elements or a danger to national security as spies etc). "
Okay and how do you check that without properly verifying who they are?
There where certain illegals who came into America who where terrorist or MS-13 Gang members. A lot of things I heard about Democrats/Progressive in America is relaxed immigration control and or not enforcing them at all.  I like your explanation, but the whole believe that illegals are uniquely capable of doing low-ed labor is kinda weird.

@Questioner Honestly, the real issue is that American businesses are really hostile to raising minimum wages (preferring automation for these kind of jobs), and Americans aren't interested in doing menial labour for low wages. Both the Democrats and the Republicans don't have any good long-term ideas to fix this. The short-term Democrat solution is indeed relaxation of immigration control and ease of naturalisation so that some of these immigrants can become American citizens. This is because American immigration policy today is to only allow skilled and educated immigrants into the country -

@Questioner - an uneducated or unskilled foreigner really has zero chances of entering America legally). Changes to immigration policy isn't happening because of political opposition. So the burden to weed out the "undesirables" amongst the illegals falls on the local police force (which it would anyway, even if a criminal or terrorist managed to enter America legally).

@sfxedit "Honestly, the real issue is that American businesses are really hostile to raising minimum wages (preferring automation for these kind of jobs)"
Well from a business point of view it does make sense.
What less makes sense is refusing to automate if there is the technology (robot fruitpickers).
"Americans aren't interested in doing menial labour for low wages"
"an uneducated or unskilled foreigner really has zero chances of entering America legally)."
Don't they have H2-B visas for Agriculture. What changed after 70s?

@Questioner Economic disparity has increased around the world, and the gap between the rich and poor in every country has widened considerably. In a globalised world, migration of labour amidst rising poverty is to be expected.

to allow even teenagers to return to factories only a small percentage of workers are employed at factories and the number keeps shrinking thanks to automation and outsourcing. Those who do work at factories only rarely do heavy physical work, again thanks to new technology. The economy is now wildly different from what it was 100 years ago and many arguments used back then make zero sense today.
